# Delete Table Header View in Interface Buidler

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have the following layout to my code
[image]

However when I hit Delete it does not delete the Table Header View. Is there a way to do this? I have been unable to find out how and there is very little on how to create a GUI from pure code without using IB.

Answer (score 0):

Found out a work around in trying to make a Sidebar like in Finder I first used NSOutlineView however if you use NSSourceList it is without the table header.